# Error with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script (below) which seems to work but prints an error every time it runs which I believe may be impacting its performance. Why am I getting this error?

The error:

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\mailserver\mail\domain.com\user\inbox\201012090411577967.imap' because it does not exist.

At C:\scripts\findfiles.ps1:27 char:21
+ $list | foreach { mv <<<<  $_.Path $newdir }
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...0411577967.imap:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

The powershell script:

```
# Prompt the user for a start directory
$startdir=Read-Host "Enter a directory to search (without trailing slash)"

# Define a variable for the new directory
$newdir="$startdir\temp"

# Make the temp directory
if (!(Test-Path -path $newdir))
{
  New-Item $newdir -type directory
}

# Tell them we will write to the start director\temp
write-host "Files will be moved to $newdir"

# Prompt to a pattern to search for
$pattern=Read-Host "Enter a pattern to search for"

# Tell the user we are doing something
write-host "Searching $startdir for `"$pattern`" then moving. Please wait...."

# Generate a list of files containing a pattern
$list = gci $startdir\* -include "*.imap" -recurse | select-string -pattern $pattern


# Move files matching the pattern to temp
$list | foreach { mv $_.Path $newdir }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-String` can find more than one match within a file.  I suspect it is finding more matches within the same file but you've already moved the file so the source doesn't exist anymore.  Use the `-List` parameter on Select-String to get just one match per file.

```
$list = gci $startdir -r *.imap | select-string $pattern -List
```

Comment: That was precisely the problem! It makes total sense - I just don't know why I didn't think of it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line that generates $list to something like this:

```
$list = gci $startdir* -include "*.imap" -recurse | where { select-string -Path $_ -Pattern $pattern -Quiet }
```

You might also want to change the last line to:

```
$list | mv $newdir
```